# 2D to 3D map OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 3d, 2d

I am trying to make a simple game engine but I got stuck at a point when I tried to map a 2D mouse coordinate to a 3D coordinate in my world. The basic game has a plane that serves as the ground as it is going to be (hopefully with time) an RTS gameengine.

My problem is that I can't really come up with anything useful. The plane is located at the 0,-100,-300 points and is about 1000x1000 in size. My camera is at 0,0,0 and the scene is rotated at 60 degreesto give the impression of a "bird eye" cam.

I was thinking about the trigonometric equations, using that I know the height of my camera and the angle and possibly calculating the distance will give me the right coords but this is just an idea.

Can somebody please give me some advice?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with the plane being located at the (0,-100,-300) points? Try specifying it with a contained point and a normal vector. You're right about using trigonometry, however.

Comment: The problem is that I would like to move my buildings around and that is why I need the coordinates.

Comment: So basically you need your mouse coordinate transformed to the "ground" coordinates of your ingame world? The title is misleading then: it's a 2D to 2D transformation.

Comment: this is a projection problem: try to project your mouse to the "ground". Search for projection tutorials. Try to find the matrix transformation for this.

Comment: This is an RTS in 3D not a 2D simple RTS. :) My game is in OpenGL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a simple ray casting.

First, using [gluUnProject](http://www.talisman.org/opengl-1.1/Reference/gluUnProject.html), you can obtain the 3D world coordinates `m` corresponding to the 2D window coordinates of the mouse pointer.

Given the camera position `e = (0, 0, 0)`,  you can compute the mouse ray direction  `r = m - e`.

Now, given a point `p` on the plane and the plane normal `n`, you can compute the [intersection of the mouse ray with the plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-plane_intersection).

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me a newer function to use? For glew maybe!

Comment: I don't know of any "newer" function.  If you are looking for a higher level set of utility functions, have a look at other (open source) scene graphs, rendering engines or game engines, such as [OGRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OGRE).